# Pyspark Data Validation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Need to do the below checks in Pyspark. We are reading data from the raw layer and storing it in the curated layer after cleansing.

1. Need to remove the null values before storing the data in the curated layer.
2. Need to remove the duplicate records.
3. If we get the same `registrationid` again, need to update the changes alone (kind of upsert) in the curated layer.

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QThJ2.png)

```
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|registrationid|dischargedate|deathdate|status_description|dischargetype|dischargesubtype|stage|remarks|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
|    1000003657|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003658|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003659|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003660|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003661|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003662|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003663|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003664|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003665|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
|    1000003666|   27/04/2023|     null|        Discharged|            N|               N|    A|   null|
+--------------+-------------+---------+------------------+-------------+----------------+-----+-------+
```

I can use `isNull` to get the null values and `dropDuplicates` to remove the duplicate records.

But how to update the records in the curated layer if I get any repeated `registrationid` in the raw layer?

Comment: better to share the data in better format, and to write the question explicitly with examples.

Comment: can you share how a record with repeated `registrationid` would look like and what is the expected result for that record?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a leftanti-join. Let's say you have your data in the curated layer in df1, and your data in your raw layer in df2.

You then remove old data from df1:

```
df1 =df1.join(df2, "registrationid", "leftanti")
```

And add the new data:

```
df_new = df1.union(df2)
```

Then you write this dataframe to your curated layer.